# Is there a way to create/retrieve the list versions in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list, custom-list

When an item changes in SharePoint a new version gets created for that row (or item) in SharePoint list. But is there a way to have (enable) the version for an entire list? So whenever item(s) change(s), a new version of the list get created.

Comment: Just curious. What is the business use case of this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint stores changes to a list with before and after values in the site's [change log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447511(v=office.14).aspx). Since this is how SharePoint stores the changes to the data, there would not be a way to just query the data you are looking for. So you would have to create it with a custom solution of your own.

You could consume the change log using a web service and filter it by a specific list, then parse that with some javascript you could get really close to a view of the list for any valid date in the change log.

You could have a audit log created by a business rule that went into a parallel list on change of any item (note that deleted items cannot trigger a business rule).

In SP 2013 business rules added looping and web services, so a business rule could take a snapshot of the entire list any time any item in the list was changed (note that deleted items cannot trigger a business rule).

You could have a developer write a solution that catches all events in a list and used that as a trigger to take a snapshot of the list.